# For statement with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I was working on a way to change to length of some code.

I had this:

```
    rects[1].setLocation(0, 0);
    rects[2].setLocation(100, 0);
    rects[3].setLocation(200, 0);
    rects[4].setLocation(300, 0);
    rects[5].setLocation(400, 0);
    rects[6].setLocation(500, 0);
    rects[7].setLocation(0, 50);
    rects[8].setLocation(100, 50);
    rects[9].setLocation(200, 50);
    rects[10].setLocation(300, 50);
    rects[11].setLocation(400, 50);
    rects[12].setLocation(500, 50);
    rects[13].setLocation(0, 100);
    rects[14].setLocation(100, 100);
    rects[15].setLocation(200, 100);
    rects[16].setLocation(300, 100);
    rects[17].setLocation(400, 100);
    rects[18].setLocation(500, 100);
    rects[19].setLocation(0, 150);
    rects[20].setLocation(100, 150);
    rects[21].setLocation(200, 150);
    rects[22].setLocation(300, 150);
    rects[23].setLocation(400, 150);
    rects[24].setLocation(500, 150);
```

And I changed it to this:

```
    for(int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 550; j +=50)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 550; k +=50)
            {
                rects[i].setLocation(j, k);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the latter doesn't work, though it should. My question is, what is the problem? I've tried many ways of fixing the problem, but nothing works. I have to way to google this quesion, because I don't know what the problem is. This is also a code from an applet, if that is noteworthy.

Comment: Your looping variables (_i, j, and k_) don't increment the way they should. Will post an answer in a moment...

Comment: You are looping 24*11*11 times while you have to loop 24 times only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    int x = (i%6)*100;
    int y = (i/6)*50;
    //Array indexes start from 1, whereas this  
    //loop starts from 0, hence adjusting below
    rects[i+1].setLocation(x, y);
}
```

You don't need three nested loops since you're assigning to only one array.

By the way, shouldn't your array indexes for `rects` start from 0?

Comment: This is algorithmically correct.  It would be nice if it could be written in a form that was more readable ... for a novice programmer.

Comment: @StephenC Good point. Refactored accordingly. You think it needs more edits?

Comment: Thank you for this, I do believe it will work. I never realized you could do just 1 for-loop and draw the variables from that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are executing the innermost statement 24 * 10 * 10 = 2400 times.

You should write this as a single loop and calculate the x and y values as sequences.

Answer (score 2):

If you trace through your code a bit, you'll find that your code does the following:

```
rects[1].setLocation(0, 0);
rects[1].setLocation(0, 50);
rects[1].setLocation(0, 100);
rects[1].setLocation(0, 150);
...
```

This is obviously not what you want.  You only need to set 24 values total, so only one loop.  You can use the modulo operator to get the appropriate values.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
{
    rects[i].setLocation(((i-1)%6)*100, ((i-1)/6)*50);
}
```

---

**A few explanations:**

[modulo operator description](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/)

The reason `(i-1)/6` will work is that this is integer division.  The result will be truncated to an integer.  For example, `11/6 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
/**  
  *  Do two things every 6th iteration:
  *
  *    1.) Reset j to zero
  *    2.) Increment k by 50
  *
  *  Otherwise increment j by 100 every iteration.
  *
  */

for (int i = 1; i < 25; i ++) {
    if (isMultipleOfSix(i)) {
        j = 0;
        k += 50;
    }
    rects[i].setLocation(j, k);
    j += 100;
}

private boolean isMultipleOfSix(int num) {
    return ( num % 6 == 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over all `j` and `k` for every value of `i`, which will end up setting all the locations to (500, 500).

What you should do is keep `j` and `k` as separate variables outside the loop (maybe call them `x`, `y`) and update them on each loop, e.g.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for(int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    rects[i].setLocation(x, y);
    if(x == 500) {
        x = 0;
        y += 50;
    } else {
        x += 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe:

```
for (int i = 0, y = 0; i <= 24; y += 50) {
  for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x += 100) {
    locs[++i].setLocation(x, y);
  }
}
```

and, no, I'm not an optimizing compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in your code that could be giving you problems:

1. your original code shows the first parameter of your
   setLocation function as incrementing by 100, whereas your for-loop
   shows it incrementint by 50.  I the original is what you want.
2. your integers i, j, and k are are created in their own
   local scope.  This means that as soon as you finish your 'k' for
   loop, k is removed from memory.  To avoid this, you can create all
   your variables outside of the original for loop.
3. You don't need all those nested for loops

Here is what I would do:

```
for(int i = 1, j = 0, k = 0; i < 24; j += 100) 
{
  if(j > 500)
  {
    j = 0;
  }

  if(i%6 == 0)
  {
    k += 50;
  }

  rects[i].setLocation(j, k);
}
```